# AmCharts incorrectly display data with 100 minute interval

Tags: amcharts

I want to display on AmChart data which is supplied every 100 minutes. But it does not show me the data every 100 minutes, only every 1h, 2h, 2h, 1h, 2h, 2h, 1h, and so on.

`categoryAxis.minPeriod` is set to "100mm"

[image: Incorrectly displayed data]
Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/765f9xsk/2/

Comment: Did you resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just take the following lines away to make it not linked to time but just one continuous graph?

```
    minPeriod: "100mm",
    parseDates: true
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/765f9xsk/4/

Comment: Thanks, but i need date parsing